# I want to convert sitecore search facet filter from multiple to single

Tags: javascript, next.js, sitecore, jss

I am trying to implement sitecore search widget and result list is working properly as expected.

I tried filter functionality using facet and by default it is multiple filter functionality.

but as per my requirement i want single select (single facet at time)

I tried but not sure how to archive this functionality.
Please help me out.

I tried this but it is not supporting single check
It is adding new selected facet id into that array
I want to remove previous and add latest

`<button onClick={() => { onFacetClick({ facetValueId: selectedArticleTypeValue?.id, facetIndex: 0, facetId: 'article_type', type: 'valueId', checked: false, }); > {jobFacet?.text} </button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work this way,

As per my understanding it is only support multiple filter in facet. so you have to right custom logic for this
what can you do

1. manage one state for selectedFacet
2. OnClick of button add logic to call this onFacetClick as well as manage that state as well
3. also add condition that if there is already selectedFacet (that you will find through state) then remove first one and then add latest

Something like this

```
if (selectedValue) {
                                    onFacetClick({
                                      facetValueId: selectedArticleTypeValue?.id,
                                      facetIndex: 0,
                                      facetId: 'article_type',
                                      type: 'valueId',
                                      checked: false,
                                    });
                                  }
                                  if (jobFacet.id) {
                                    onFacetClick({
                                      facetValueId: jobFacet.id,
                                      facetIndex: 0,
                                      facetId: 'article_type',
                                      type: 'valueId',
                                      checked: true,
                                    });
                                  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I think i found proper way or approach for this scenario. Let me try this